# Opening closable tabs using push button in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I am making a GUI program in Qt.

I have one tab and in that tab there is push button, what I want is when that button is clicked then it should open a tab in the same widget and it should be closable.
How can I do that? A example code will be good.

Thank you

Comment: what i understand is that there are two tabs in one parent widget: tabA and tabB; and, when u click a button inside tabA, tabB should be opend. that can be done.
but, what do you mean "closable"?

Comment: I meant this
Suppose my program starts then it should have only 1 tab i.e tabA visible and when pushbutton is clicked then it should open tab B and it should have close button on that tab, like in Google Chrome tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not fully understand the question, but here is my best attempt at answering it. I suppose that you use `QTabWidget` for your tabs. You can add a widget and select it by the following code:

```
QWidget* widget;
int index = ui->tabWidget->addTab(widget, "Description");
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

You cannot make single tabs closable, but you can intercept the close event:

```
ui->tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));
```

And handle unwanted close events like this:

```
void MainWindow::closeTab(int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        return; // don't close the first tab
    }
    QWidget* widget = ui->tabWidget->widget(index);
    ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
    delete widget;
}
```

**EDIT**:

You can insert Tabs with:

```
ui->tabWidget->insertTab(index, widget, "Description");
```

Here is the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) for the `QTabWidget` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

can you pls tell me how to hide single tabs and show them?For hiding tab I used ui->tabWidget->removeTab(3) , this is successful but I dont know how to show it back. Can you pls tell me?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it like this ui->tabWidget->insertTab(3, ui->tabWidget, "My Tab");    but when I click the button to which I connected this then my program gets stuck and stops responding. What I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add the tabWidget to itself in a tab, tell it which widget should be added:`ui->tabWidget->insertTab(3, widgetThatYouWantToDisplay, "My Tab");`

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, when I click button then the tab opens up now but annoying thing is, it opens to the left side of the tab in which button is present. I want it to open on extreme right side like how Google Chrome opens a tab. How can i do that? And is there really no way to set single tabs withing tabwidget closable?

Comment: Thanks I got that too working but really need individual tabs closable, s it possible in any way?

Comment: Would you like to share how you added open Tab "+" button in qt?